# How entity framework SaveChanges works?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I try to understand how EF creates DB requests from object manipulations in code. My test scenario is simple:

```
using(var context = new Context())
{
var entity = context.Entities.First();
entity.A = "TST";
entity.B = "WrongValue";
context.SaveChanges();
}
```

My idea is to test, how EF deal with transaction.
Change A with correct value and change B with wrong value (non existing FK)
I track what happening in SQL Server DB.
I execute code and nothing change in DB, that was expected.
Strange part is that there are two independant SQL request and I don't understand how EF revert first one.

Comment: When SaveChanges() is executed to insert, update or delete on the database then Entity framework will wrap that operation in a transaction. This transaction lasts only long enough to execute the operation and then completes. When you execute another such operation a new transaction is started. This happens when no external transaction is not provided. If an external transaction is provided then EF uses that instead of creating new interally.

Comment: EF don't revert any change. It just rollback transaction then SqlServer rollback all change at transaction scope.

Comment: yes, but how this happen? In SQL profiler I could see only 2 requests to SQL Server. There is not "BEGIN TRAN".....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both `Entity Framework` and `EntityFramework core` code are open source. You can check the code at

1. Entity Framework - [Link](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/)
2. Entity Framework Core - [Link](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore)

If you see the internal code of [Save method](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/ObjectContext.cs#L3020) (pasted the code snapshot below) then you can validate that it internally it creates a transaction if an external transaction is not provided.

```
    internal int SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, bool executeInExistingTransaction)
    {
        AsyncMonitor.EnsureNotEntered();

        PrepareToSaveChanges(options);

        var entriesAffected = 0;

        // if there are no changes to save, perform fast exit to avoid interacting with or starting of new transactions
        if (ObjectStateManager.HasChanges())
        {
            if (executeInExistingTransaction)
            {
                entriesAffected = SaveChangesToStore(options, null, startLocalTransaction: false);
            }
            else
            {
                var executionStrategy = DbProviderServices.GetExecutionStrategy(Connection, MetadataWorkspace);
                entriesAffected = executionStrategy.Execute(
                    () => SaveChangesToStore(options, executionStrategy, startLocalTransaction: true));
            }
        }

        ObjectStateManager.AssertAllForeignKeyIndexEntriesAreValid();
        return entriesAffected;
    }
```

So your below code will internally wrapped inside a transaction which you can validate in SQL Profiler..

```
using(var context = new Context())
{
var entity = context.Entities.First();
entity.A = "TST";
entity.B = "WrongValue";
context.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, SQL profiler does not start logging transaction so you need to configure that in trace setting. See the below screenshot of SQL profiler new Trace setting, here, I have checked `Show All events`. After that `Transaction` category is being displayed. You can subscribe for `Begin Tran`, `Commit Tran` and `Rollback Tran` events to validate transaction statements. When you will run your scenario, you can see that Begin and Rollback should be logged. [image]

Comment: Please don't provide an answer using external links. Please put the content in your answer and link externally only as a supporting reference.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Does my answer don't provide the clarity here? The question, how SaveChanges works which I describe in my answer using external link as it required. In the comment section, the user has asked about transactions are not being logged, so which I've also provided with SQL profiler tool. Not sure what is not clear.

Comment: I think your answer would be excellent if the code for https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/ObjectContext.cs#L3020 where in the answer and not just as a link.

Comment: Because you were linking to external content. That's a no-no here. The content should be in your directly in your answer and only linked to as a supporting reference.

Comment: Thanks. Will keep that in mind for future responses :).